# Command line utility to dial a phone (bluetooth mobile) on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, bluetooth

Is there a **command line** utility that would allow me to dial a number on mobile (send a ATD +xxxxx;) phone - preferably connected using bluetooth? I can do this very easily on Linux, but cannot find a way on Windows.